# Sum of a value inside a list/tuple trouble

Tags: python

I can't seem to figure out how to get the sum of the values insisde the list/tuples

I've tried using keys and a few other methods, none of which work

```
#initialise variables
products = []
totalCost = 0.0


#input products and prices funtions
def getInput():
    product_name = input("What is the product?")
    product_price = input("What s the price?")

    return (product_name, product_price)

#collect input
for x in range(5):
    product = getInput()
    products.append(product)

#sort list
products.sort(key=lambda t: t[1], reverse=True)


#show list
def showTable():
    for x in range(5):
        print("Product Name | Price: ", products[x])

#calculate cheapest
def cheapestItem():
    print("The cheapest item in this list is: ", min(products, key = lambda t: t[1]))
    print("Congratulations you get this item free")

    #calculate total
    totalCost = sum(products[1]) - min(products[1])


#main
showTable()
cheapestItem()
```

I want to get the sum of the prices and subtract the smallest amount from that list.

Comment: I can't see any summing, can you provide the minimal version to reproduce your problem?

Comment: What would be the expected output?

Comment: But just reducing it is not sensible because you are not removing that item?

Answer (score 1):

```
products = [('a',1),('b',2),('c',30),('d',10),('e',5)]

totalcost = sum([x[1] for x in products]) - min(products, key=lambda x:x[1])[1]

print(totalcost)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have several problems:

**You do not have numbers, only strings:**

> ```
> def getInput():
>     product_name = input("What is the product?")   # string
>     product_price = input("What s the price?")     # string
>
>     return (product_name, product_price)
> ```

Fix (just the price input part):

```
      while True:
          try: 
              product_price = int(input("What s the price?"))
              if product_price <= 0:
                  raise ValueError
              break
          except ValueError:
              print("Not a valid price")
```

See [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response) to see other methods how to avoid `ValueError`s.

As long as you do not have numbers, `'1000'` will be less then `'2'` (alphabetical comparison).

**Your cheapest item calculations does not do what it is supposed to do:**

Even if you fix your products to have numbers, your `totalCost` does not work:

> ```
> product[1] # this is the 2nd element of your list - not the price of it
>
>
> def cheapestItem():
>     print("The cheapest item in this list is: ", min(products, key = lambda t: t[1]))
>     print("Congratulations you get this item free")
>
>     #calculate total
>     totalCost = sum(products[1]) - min(products[1])
> ```

Fix (f.e.):

```
   # assumes numbers in ("icecream", 42) - not strings
   sortedItems = sorted(products, lambda x:x[1])  # sort by price ascending

   minItem   = sortedItems[0]
   totalCost = sum(item[1] for item in sortedItems[1:])   # don't calc the lowest value
   totalCost = sum(products[1]) - min(products[1])
```

Using `min()` would work as well, but by sorting you can use list slicing to sum all but the lowest. If you have **huge** lists - `min()` is more optimal:

```
   minItem = min(products, lambda x:x[1])
   total = sum(item[1] for item in products) - minItem[1]  # reduced by minItems cost
```

---

I fixed the code to use parameters provided to the functions and not a global one - also there is no need to min() the products list because you sort it anyway - you can simply slice away the lowest item and deduct its value:

Fixed code & example input:

```
def getInput():
    product_name = input("What is the product? ")
    while True: 
        try:
            # whole number prices assumed, else use float( input ( ... ))
            product_price = int(input("What s the price? "))
            if product_price <= 0:
                raise ValueError
            break
        except ValueError:
            print("Wrong input - prices must be greater 0 and whole numbers")

    return (product_name, product_price)

def showTable(p):
    for x in p:
        print("Product Name | Price: ", x[0],x[1])

def cheapestItem(p):
    # assumes sorted list of items in p
    print("The cheapest item in this list is: ", p[-1])
    print("Congratulations you get this item free")

    #calculate total
    totalCost = sum(i[1] for i in p[:-1])
    print("Total Cost:", totalCost, "You saved:", p[-1])


products = [] 
for x in range(5):
    product = getInput()
    products.append(product)

# sort list - cheapestItem(..) needs a sorted input to work
products.sort(key=lambda t: t[1], reverse=True)

showTable(products)
cheapestItem(products)
```

Output:

```
What is the product? apple
What s the price? 22
What is the product? pear
What s the price? 11
What is the product? kiwi
What s the price? 5
What is the product? pineapple
What s the price? no idea
Wrong input - prices must be greater 0 and whole numbers
What s the price? 100
What is the product? gears
What s the price? 1

Product Name | Price:  pineapple 100
Product Name | Price:  apple 22
Product Name | Price:  pear 11
Product Name | Price:  kiwi 5
Product Name | Price:  gears 1
The cheapest item in this list is:  ('gears', 1)
Congratulations you get this item free
Total Cost: 138 You saved: ('gears', 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#initialise variables
products = []
totalCost = 0.0


#input products and prices funtions
def getInput():
    product_name = input("What is the product?")
    product_price = int(input("What s the price?"))

    return (product_name, product_price)

#collect input
for x in range(5):
    product = getInput()
    products.append(product)

#sort list
products.sort(key=lambda t: t[1], reverse=True)


#show list
def showTable():
    for x in range(5):
        print("Product Name | Price: ", products[x])

#calculate cheapest
def cheapestItem():
    print("The cheapest item in this list is: ", min(price))
    print("Congratulations you get this item free")


price = []
for i in range(len(products)):
    price.append(products[i][1])

totalCost = sum(price) - min(price)
print(totalCost)

#main
showTable()
cheapestItem()
```

You can't pass a list of tuples to sum(). It take a list of numbers.

Answer (score -1):

If I got this right, this should work:

```
products.remove(min(products))
print(sum(products))
```

Comment: It makes sense to remove an item but you can't sum a list of tuples like that.